# Will previous 301 redirect still be cached if site switches to using SSL?

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, https, cache

For reasons only my past self knows I put a 301 redirect in place to force all traffic to `example.org` from `www.example.org`. Put simply it dropped the `www.` subdomain.

Now I would like to change it so that all traffic goes to the `www.` subdomain, which would be problematic as any cached 301s in user's browsers would send the user into a redirect loop.

So I am planning on buying an SSL certificate and encrypting all traffic on the site - for other reasons too. If I redirect the users to `https://www.example.org/` will it still cause the browser to look at it's cache and go into a redirect loop again?

To my mind `https://www.example.org` is a different URL to `http://www.example.org`, but do all the browsers see it this way for caching purposes?

Comment: I don't think this would cause a "redirect loop"? (Have you experienced this and the browsers cache was the problem?) I would have thought this might result in two redirects - at worst - so I can't see this being a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to double check the specifications, but I am pretty certain that cached objects depend on the request method.

So an object using `HTTP` would be a different cache entity from `HTTPS`.

So if you are redirecting to `HTTPS`, there should be no prior cache data.

Also, you may want to consider using lower cache periods and requiring validation prior to the change:

`Cache-Control "max-age=3600, must-revalidate"`

This should force the user agent to revalidate the content and pick up your changes faster - even if there's a caching issue.

Note that this is controlled on the client side, so various browsers/user-agents could behave differently.